# How to delete multiple items with GraphQL?

Tags: datatables, graphql, mutation

I am new in GraphQL.
How can I write a delete mutation to delete multiple items (more than one ID) in GraphQL?
I use scaphold.io.

Answer (score 16):

You can batch multiple mutations in the same request to the GraphQL server using *GraphQL aliases*.

Let's say this is how you delete one Item:

```
mutation deleteOne {
  deleteItem(id: "id1") {
    id
  }
}
```

Then this is how you can delete multiple items in one request:

```
mutation deleteMultiple {
  id1: deleteItem(id: "id1") {
    id
  }
  id2: deleteItem(id: "id2") {
    id
  }
  # ... and so on
  id100: deleteItem(id: "id100") {
    id
  }
}
```

It's helpful to know that **multiple mutations in one request run sequentially** in the stated order (from top to bottom). You can also run multiple queries in one request the same way, and **multiple queries in one request run in parellel**.

If you want to run say 1000 mutations, it might be better to batch them in 10 groups of 100.

More information and another example can be found in this [FAQ article](https://www.graph.cool/docs/faq/graphql-multiple-requests-cahzai2eur) as well as the official [GraphQL docs](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#multiple-fields-in-mutations).

Comment: Link to FAQ article is broken.

Comment: adding multiple delete is not possible , if i delete 100 ?

Answer (score 3):

I think that good solution would be to create a method (mutation) that accepts array of e.g. IDs, that are further used to batch delete multiple records from the database.

```
mutation deleteUsers($userIds: [Int!]!) {
    deleteUsers(userIds: $userIds) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Then, in the resolver you could use the `userIds` parameter to perform an SQL query like `DELETE FROM users WHERE id IN userIds`, where `userIds` of course should be correctly replaced (escaped), depending on how you interact with the database.

Comment: it works but how can you return the multiple objects that have been deleted with the GraphQL mutation, so that you can build a log message such as : "X,  Y, and Z have been deleted" ?